# Ruby code understanding - From code School

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

)
I am learning ruby via the very good website code School, however in one of their examples I do not understand the method and the logic behind, could someone explain me ?

Thank you so much ;-)

Here is the code

```
search = "" unless search 
games = ["Super Mario Bros.", "Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man 2"]
matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
puts "Found the following games..."
matched_games.each do |game|
  puts "- #{game}"
end
```

I do not really understand line 1 and 3

```
search = "" unless search 

matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement assigns empty string to `search` variable if `search` is not defined.

```
search = "" unless search
```

Had this assignment not be done, `Regexp.new` would have thrown an `TypeError` with message `no implicit conversion of nil into String`, or if search was not defined then `NameError` with message undefined local variable or method 'search'...

In the following statement:

```
matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
```

`games.grep(pattern)` returns an array of every element that matches the pattern.  For further details please refer to [grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).  `Regexp.new(search)` constructs a new regular expression from the supplied `search` variable which can either be a string or a regular expression pattern.  Again, for further details please reference [Regexp::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-new)

So say for example search is `""` (empty string), then `Regexp.new(search)` returns `//`, if search = 'Super Mario Bros.' then `Regexp.new(search)` returns `/Super Mario Bros./`.

Now the pattern matching:

```
# For search = "", or Regexp.new(search) = //
matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
Result: matched_games = ["Super Mario Bros.", "Contra", "Metroid", "Mega Man 2"]

# For search = "Super Mario Bros.", or Regexp.new(search) = /Super Mario Bros./
matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
Result: matched_games = ["Super Mario Bros."]

# For search = "something", or Regexp.new(search) = /something/
matched_games = games.grep(Regexp.new(search))
Result: matched_games = []
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Search should be instance of *Regexp* or nil. In first line *search* is setting to blank string if it's equal to nil initially.

In third string *matched_games* is setting to array of strings matched to given regex (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep)

Comment: Hey thx for the answer ;-)
Could you just explain me the difference between the Regexp.new anf the grep method they look kind of similar ?

Comment: _Regexp.new_ creates instance of _Regexp_ class. _grep_ uses this instance to filter certain array.

Answer (score 0):

vinodadhikary said all. I just don't like the syntax OP mentioned

```
search = "" unless search
```

This is nicer

```
search ||= ""
```

Comment: Hey thx you ;-)
It was exactly the purpose of the exercise in the Code school lesson

Comment: Oh, it seems I have passed it :)